# Finding a formula for a random variable (discrete)

Tags: probability

> Suppose you shoot three times independently. The probability of
>   hitting the target in the first try, second try and third try is
>   $0.7,0.5$ and $0.4$ accordingly. Let $X$ be the discrete random
>   variable representing the number of successful shots among these
>   three. Find a formula of the piecewise function $X: \Omega \to
>  \mathbb{R}$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space.

$$ \underline{Attempt} $$

I am having trouble trying to find the sample space $\Omega$. What I do know is that Range of $X$ is $\{0,1,2,3\}$. Now I need some $A$ events so that $X(A) = i$ whre $i=1,2,3, $ or $0$. How can I find such $A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sample space were all the possible outcomes of the three attempts, so with $2^3=8$ elements say of the form $$\Omega=\{HHH,HHM, HMH,HMM,MHH,MHM,MMH,MMM\}$$
with the function $X$ simply counting the number of hits in an element

Answer (score 0):

Since X is a discrete random variable, find each probability separately:

$P(x=0) = .3 *.5*.6$ (Miss on all 3 shots)

$P(x=1)=.7*.5*.6+.3*.5*.6+.3*.5*.4$ (Hit on first attempt, miss on the next two; hit on second attempt, miss on attempts 1 and 3; hit on third attempt, miss on 1 and 2)

You can find $P(x=2), P(x=3)$.

Your function will have the domain of $\{0,1,2,3\}$, where each number represents the number of successful shots, and the values for each number will be the probabilities we found above.